# Why will flash videos not start until fully loaded?

Tags: windows-vista, flash-player

All of a sudden, flash videos won't start until all of the movie is loaded. Affects every flash movie youtube, brake.com, my own videos.. I have Vista SP1 and I have tried uninstalling / reinstalling flash player.

Comment: What web browser are you using?

Comment: Browser and version number would help.  It also wouldn't hurt to update Vista to SP2 (although probably not an issue here).

Comment: Affects all browsers (Chrome 2, Firefox 3.5 and IE8).

Answer (score 1):

If you have uninstall flash through the "add/remove programs", it might not be totally uninstalled.

Try the official Flash Uninstaller here, remember to reboot windows before reinstalling: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html#uninstaller